# Ajax call to perl script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl

I am using perl Mason for web development.

I have an application, that takes data from user uploaded file, and puts it into a html table.

Then, I want to digest the data, and after user validation, save it to csv file on the server.

I tried AJAX call from javascript grabbing data from the table to perl receiver, but that doesn't seem to work... (error log does not show anything, file is not created, as if the script was not invoked, though access log shows successful POST towards **`receiver.pl`**)

My code is as follows:

#### HTML

The table contains a lot of rows, about 200, if that matters.

```html
<div>
  <button id="btnConvert">Update Data</button>
</div>
<table id="v12">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>some data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>some data3</td>
    </tr>
    [...]
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnConvert').click(function() {
    var tableData = JSON.stringify(makeJsonFromTable('v12'));
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'receiver.pl',
      data: {
        r: tableData
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('string saved to file');
        console.log(tableData);
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  });
});
```

#### Converting table to JSON

```js
var makeJsonFromTable=function(a){
var b=$("#"+a),c=$(b).find("thead"),d=$(b).find("tbody"),e=$(b).find("tbody>tr").length,f=[],g=[];
$.each($(c).find("tr>th"),function(a,b){f.push($(b).text())}),$.each($(d).find("tr"),function(a,b){for(var c={},d=0;d<f.length;d++)c[f[d]]=$(this).find("td").eq(d).text();g.push(c)});
var h={};return h.count=e,h.value=g,h
};
```

#### Perl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw(-debug);
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';

my $cgi = CGI->new;
print $cgi->header('application/json;charset=UTF-8');
my $string = $cgi->param('r');
print $string;
open (FILE, ">", "text.txt") || die "Could not open: $!";
print FILE $string;
close FILE;
```

Browser side, I can see the data is being passed in Params (seen in browser developer tools), but it seems the **`receiver.pl`** doesn't seem to get the data.

What could the issue here be?

### EDIT

When running **`receiver.pl`** from command line, the data is parsed:

```
# QUERY_STRING="r={dasdsa}" ./receiver.pl 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{dasdsa}
```

Comment: [You should avoid the CGI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE)

Comment: @Quentin, I'm aware of that, but the perl version I have available will not be upgraded that fast

Comment: Why are you encoding the result as JSON? It is *already* JSON.

Comment: Using an old version of Perl is not a good reason to use out of date programming techniques!

Comment: "it seems the receiver.pl doesn't seem to get the data." —  How can you tell? What do the logs say? Does the file get written? Does it have *anything* in it?

Comment: @Quentin, problem is logs do not show anything, file is not created, as if the script was not invoked, though access log shows successful POST towards receiver.pl

Comment: I'd start by adding more logs (adding some `warn $string` for example) and simplifying the script (e.g. by removing all use the JSON module for it)

Comment: you don't specify the full path for the output file, so how do you know where it will end up?

Comment: @ChrisTurner yes, that is on purpose for sake of this question

Comment: Doublecheck the URL

Comment: @Holli URL is fine as it's logged in apache access log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem in my case was Apache missing CGI execution handler... Had to add

```
<Files ~ "\.(pl|cgi)$">
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
    Options +ExecCGI
    PerlSendHeader On
</Files>
```